# Copying, pasting and deleting codependent ranges to different sheets in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function, worksheet-function

I have a sheet, let's call it `sheetA`. I have a range of fields in that sheet (`rangeA`) which has formulas that determine two more ranges in the same sheet. Let's call them `rangeB` and `rangeC`.  Once these are determined, I want to copy `rangeB` and `rangeC` into sheets `sheetB` and `sheetC` respectively. Once that is done, I would like to delete `rangeA`. A reset of sorts so that I can enter new values in that range manually and repeat the process.

I want to have a function/button that can accomplish this. I have tried the following:

```
Private Sub TransferPuzzleButton1_Click()

    FirstOperation
    GetFirstEmptyCell1 "sht As Worksheet", "row As Long"
    SecondOperation
    GetFirstEmptyCell1 "sht As Worksheet", "row As Long"
    ClearCell

End Sub

Sub FirstOperation()
    Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim destSht As Worksheet: Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    GetFirstEmptyCell(destSht, 1).Resize(25).Value = sourceSht.Range("A1:A27").Value
End Sub

Function GetFirstEmptyCell1(sht As Worksheet, row As Long) As Range
    Set GetFirstEmptyCell = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    If Not IsEmpty(GetFirstEmptyCell) Then Set GetFirstEmptyCell = GetFirstEmptyCell.Offset(, 1)

End Function
Sub SecondOperation()
    Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim destSht As Worksheet: Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    GetFirstEmptyCell(destSht, 1).Resize(2).Value = sourceSht.Range("C1:C2").Value

End Sub
Function GetFirstEmptyCell2(sht As Worksheet, row As Long) As Range
    Set GetFirstEmptyCell = sht.Cells(1, 2).End(xlToLeft) '
    If Not IsEmpty(GetFirstEmptyCell) Then Set GetFirstEmptyCell = GetFirstEmptyCell.Offset(, 1)
End Function
Sub ClearCell()
    Dim sourceSht As Worksheet: Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    sourceSht.Range("F7:I10").Clear
    sourceSht.Range("C1:C2").Clear
End Sub
```

It seems I'm mangling the beginning `Sub` calls somehow

Answer (score 0):

With `GetFirstEmptyCell1 "sht As Worksheet", "row As Long"` you are trying to call a sub that takes arguments. The argument typing is done in the definition of the sub, not in the statement that calls the sub.

When you call the sub you need to supply the parameters that it expects, in this case a worksheet and a long.

So, get your data ready before you call the sub. Abbreviated:

```
Private Sub TransferPuzzleButton1_Click()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
dim myNumber as Long
Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DemoSheet")
MyNumber = 1000

' now call the function

    GetFirstEmptyCell1 mySheet, myNumber

End Sub


    Function GetFirstEmptyCell1(sht As Worksheet, row As Long) As Range
        Set GetFirstEmptyCell = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        If Not IsEmpty(GetFirstEmptyCell) Then Set GetFirstEmptyCell = GetFirstEmptyCell.Offset(, 1)

    End Function
```

By the way, the names you use inside the function are not consistent. GetFirstEmptyCell1 vs GetFirstEmptyCell.